# UIStackView of subviews not Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have a UIScrollView to which I have added a UIStackView of subviews.  The subviews aren't scrollable, yet if I add buttons instead of UIViews, the stack view *is* scrollable. This code appears in the Detail View of a split view controller.  Any idea as to why subviews aren't scrolling?
BTW the detailItem will carry the index, but for now I am hardcoding the index[4] for a guaranteed long scrollworthy list.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var stackView: UIStackView!

    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view.
     //   self.configureView()
     //   print("didSet: configureView")
        }
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView": scrollView]))


    stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .Vertical

    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
    scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
 /*
    for _ in 1 ..< 100 {
        let vw = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
        vw.setTitle("Button", forState: .Normal)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw)
    }
 */

    let selectedGroup: Group = GroupArray[4]

    let descriptorsArray = selectedGroup.descriptorsArray

    for descriptor in descriptorsArray {
        // Create a subview for each descriptor

        let subView = UIView()
        subView.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.view.frame.width-10, 50)
        subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        subView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50.0).active = true
        // Create a label for Descriptor subview
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 200, 46))
        label.text = descriptor.name
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(22.0)
        label.textAlignment = .Left
        label.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()

        subView.addSubview(label)
        // Create a button for Checkbox

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(subView)

     }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a constraint:

```
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[stackView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[stackView]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView]))
```

You have forgotten to pin the stack view to the bottom of the scroll view. Without that, the scroll view has no `contentSize`. Without a `contentSize`, no scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, matt.  You reminded me of something I tried with the content before, but it didn't work because previously I didn't have the proper constraints, I guess.  I added this line and it scrolls: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

@Jolly You can try **ScrollableStackView** : https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView

It's Objective-C and Swift compatible library. It's available through [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html).

**Sample Code**

```
import ScrollableStackView

var scrollable = ScrollableStackView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scrollable)

// add your views with 
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 55))
rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollable.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rectangle)
// ...
```